# Requeue or delete messages in Azure Storage Queues via WebJobs

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-storage-queues

I was hoping if someone can clarify a few things regarding Azure Storage Queues and their interaction with WebJobs:

1. To perform recurring background tasks (i.e. add to queue once, then repeat at set intervals), is there a way to update the same message delivered in the QueueTrigger function so that its lease (visibility) can be extended as a way to requeue and avoid expiry?
2. With the above-mentioned pattern for recurring background jobs, I'm also trying to figure out a way to delete/expire a job 'on demand'. Since this doesn't seem possible outside the context of WebJobs, I was thinking of maybe storing the messageId and popReceipt for the message(s) to be deleted in Table storage as persistent cache, and then upon delivery of message in the QueueTrigger function do a Table lookup to perform a DeleteMessage, so that the message is not repeated any more.

Any suggestions or tips are appreciated. Cheers :)

Answer (score 7):

Azure Storage Queues are used to store messages that may be consumed by your Azure Webjob, WorkerRole, etc. The Azure Webjobs SDK provides an easy way to interact with Azure Storage (that includes Queues, Table Storage, Blobs, and Service Bus). That being said, you can also have an Azure Webjob that does not use the Webjobs SDK and does not interact with Azure Storage. In fact, I do run a Webjob that interacts with a SQL Azure database.

I'll briefly explain how the Webjobs SDK interact with Azure Queues. Once a message arrives to a queue (or is made 'visible', more on this later) the function in the Webjob is triggered (assuming you're running in continuous mode). If that function returns with no error, the message is deleted. If something goes wrong, the message goes back to the queue to be processed again. You can handle the failed message accordingly. [Here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/#poison) is an example on how to do this.

> The SDK will call a function up to 5 times to process a queue message. If the fifth try fails, the message is moved to a poison queue. The maximum number of retries is configurable.

Regarding visibility, when you add a message to the queue, there is a visibility timeout property. By default is zero. Therefore, if you want to process a message in the future you can do it (up to 7 days in the future) by setting this property to a desired value.

> Optional. If specified, the request must be made using an x-ms-version of 2011-08-18 or newer. If not specified, the default value is 0. Specifies the new visibility timeout value, in seconds, relative to server time. The new value must be larger than or equal to 0, and cannot be larger than 7 days. The visibility timeout of a message cannot be set to a value later than the expiry time. visibilitytimeout should be set to a value smaller than the time-to-live value.

Now the suggestions for your app.

1. I would just add a message to the queue for every task that you want to accomplish. The message will obviously have the pertinent information for processing. If you need to schedule several tasks, you can run a Scheduled Webjob (on a schedule of your choice) that adds messages to the queue. Then your continuous Webjob will pick up that message and process it.
2. Add a GUID to each message that goes to the queue. Store that GUID in some other domain of your application (a database). So when you dequeue the message for processing, the first thing you do is check against your database if the message needs to be processed. If you need to cancel the execution of a message, instead of deleting it from the queue, just update the GUID in your database.

There's more info [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179346.aspx)

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the details. It doesn't specifically answer my first question: can a message lease extended in the function?

Comment: No, I don't think you can. And if  you do, I think it's not a good practice. You can re add the original message from the function you're executing  with a visibilityTimeout of up to 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

As for the first part of the question, you can use the Update Message operation to extend the visibility timeout of a message.

> The Update Message operation can be used to continually extend the
>   invisibility of a queue message. This functionality can be useful if
>   you want a worker role to “lease” a queue message. For example, if a
>   worker role calls Get Messages and recognizes that it needs more time
>   to process a message, it can continually extend the message’s
>   invisibility until it is processed. If the worker role were to fail
>   during processing, eventually the message would become visible again
>   and another worker role could process it.

You can check the REST API documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452234.aspx

For the second part of your question, there are really multiple ways and your method of storing the id/popReceipt as a lookup is a possible option, you can actually have a Web Job dedicated to receive messages on a different queue (e.g plz-delete-msg) and you send a message containing the "messageId" and this Web Job can use Get Message operation then Delete it. (you can make the job generic by passing the queue name!)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179474.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179347.aspx